# Flutter BezierChart Data issues

Tags: flutter, dynamic

I'm attempting to create a chart in flutter that has its coordinates or points dynamically change based on an array but currently, as I do that using the bezierChart package I get the following problem stating that "The element type 'Set>' can't be assigned to the list type 'DataPoint'." this error is directly derived from the for loop line inside data of which u can see from the code snippet I linked below. Is there any way to dynamically pass datapoints to this data section so that I can have X amount of data points as opposed to having a predetermined amount of datapoints.

```
Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                  child: BezierChart(
                  bezierChartScale: BezierChartScale.MONTHLY,
                  fromDate: fromDate,
                  toDate: toDate,
                  selectedDate: toDate,
                  series: [
                    BezierLine(
                      label: "Weight Monthly Comparison",
                      onMissingValue: (dateTime) {
                        if (dateTime.month.isEven) {
                          return 0.0;
                        }
                        return 0.0;
                      },
                      data: [
                        //ERROR OCCURS INSIDE HERE
                          for (var i = 0; i < progressionList[index].weight.length; i++) 
                          {
                            DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: progressionList[index].timeupdate[0]),
                          }
                        //DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: progressionList[index].timeupdate[0]),
                        // DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: date1),
                        // DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: date2),
                        // DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: date3),
                        // DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: date4),
                        // DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: date5),
                        // DataPoint<DateTime>(value: (progressionList[index].weight[0]).toDouble(), xAxis: date6),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                  config: BezierChartConfig(
                    verticalIndicatorStrokeWidth: 3.0,
                    verticalIndicatorColor: Colors.black26,
                    showVerticalIndicator: true,
                    verticalIndicatorFixedPosition: false,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    footerHeight: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can do for loop in `build` and use `dataPointList.add` 
code snippet

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<DataPoint<DateTime>> dataPointList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < progressionList.length; i++) {
      dataPointList.add(DataPoint<DateTime>(
          value: progressionList[i].weight.toDouble(),
          xAxis: progressionList[i].timeupdate));
    }
... 
BezierLine(
                  label: "Weight Monthly Comparison",
                  onMissingValue: (dateTime) {
                    if (dateTime.month.isEven) {
                      return 0.0;
                    }
                    return 0.0;
                  },
                  data: dataPointList),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bezier_chart/bezier_chart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Progression {
  int weight;
  DateTime timeupdate;

  Progression({this.weight, this.timeupdate});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final fromDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 300));
  final toDate = DateTime.now();

  List<Progression> progressionList = [
    Progression(
        weight: 50, timeupdate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2))),
    Progression(
        weight: 60, timeupdate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 30))),
    Progression(
        weight: 70, timeupdate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 50))),
    Progression(
        weight: 80, timeupdate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 60)))
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<DataPoint<DateTime>> dataPointList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < progressionList.length; i++) {
      dataPointList.add(DataPoint<DateTime>(
          value: progressionList[i].weight.toDouble(),
          xAxis: progressionList[i].timeupdate));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              child: BezierChart(
                bezierChartScale: BezierChartScale.MONTHLY,
                fromDate: fromDate,
                toDate: toDate,
                selectedDate: toDate,
                series: [
                  BezierLine(
                      label: "Weight Monthly Comparison",
                      onMissingValue: (dateTime) {
                        if (dateTime.month.isEven) {
                          return 0.0;
                        }
                        return 0.0;
                      },
                      data: dataPointList),
                ],
                config: BezierChartConfig(
                  verticalIndicatorStrokeWidth: 3.0,
                  verticalIndicatorColor: Colors.black26,
                  showVerticalIndicator: true,
                  verticalIndicatorFixedPosition: false,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  footerHeight: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate *List* method for looping and returning the whole list.

One of simplest examples,

```
List<DataPoint> makeDataPoints() {
 List<DataPoint> dataPointList = [];
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
   dataPointList.add(DataPoint<DateTime>(
      value: i, xAxis: DateTime(2020, 10, 01, i, 00)));
 }
return dataPointList;
}
```

make all the necessary modifications to the loop conditions and body and call this method from usual data point location,

*data: makeDataPoints ( )* :

```
series: [
  BezierLine(
    label: "Line Name",
    data: makeDataPoints(),
  ),
],
```